# iOS Amazon S3 download large files

Tags: ios, debugging, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I'm quite new to Amazon S3 and I'm having difficulty downloading large files from S3.

I have successfully downloaded a file that is 35MB every time, but when the size of the file is really big around 500 MB - 1.7GB the application crashes.

When trying on the simulator I would get can't allocate region error after about 1GB of the download.

So then I tried it on the device.  Now it seems to just crash at a random time and

no crash report is put in the device, therefor I'm having an issue debugging this problem.

At first I thought it was the device or even the simulator. But i'm not really sure.

Someone mentioned that S3 framework times out the downloads randomly occasionally for large files. Could this be the case?

I'm building the file by opening a data file seeking to the end, adding the data, then closing the file until the download is complete.

I'm not sure how to debug this problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S3GetObjectRequest has NSMutableData* body where it appends all the data it downloads.

For large files as download progresses data is appended constantly, and it goes over the VM limit of 90MB and then app gets killed by iOS.

Quick and dirty workaround is to create your own S3GetObjectRequest and S3GetObjectResponse classes. AWS framework instantiates Response based on Class Name of Request (Class name of Request without last 7 chars "Request" and appends it with "Response", and tries to instantiate new class of that name).

Then to override **-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data** to release body all the time.

This is quick and dirty fix simply because you still have constant data allocation, appending and then release. But it works when you are in a pinch. For my usage of downloading files of 150-700mb, this simple hack kept memory usage of the app at 2.55mb average, +/- 0.2mb.

As stated by the author of ASIHTTP library, it is no longer maintained.

Request - LargeFileS3GetObjectRequest.h

```
@interface LargeFileS3GetObjectRequest : S3GetObjectRequest
@end
```

Request - LargeFileS3GetObjectRequest.m

```
@implementation LargeFileS3GetObjectRequest
@end
```

Response -  LargeFileS3GetObjectResponse.h

```
@interface LargeFileS3GetObjectResponse : S3GetObjectResponse
@end
```

Response - LargeFileS3GetObjectResponse.m

```
@implementation LargeFileS3GetObjectResponse

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    // allow original implementation to send data to delegates
    [super connection:connection didReceiveData:data];

    // release body and set it to NULL so that underlying implementation doesn't
    // append on released object, but instead allocates new one
    [body release];
    body = NULL;
}
@end
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm using AWS implementation no ASIHTTP.  When I tested out my 1.5 gig download with an app that only did a download it never crashed. If I take that code and put it back in my application the app crashes.  SO you're thinking the LArgeFileS3GetObjectResponse.m  example there fixes that problem?

Comment: I needed a way to get data in chunks for some project, while downloading multiple files simultaneously, so I went through ASW S3 source and made this quick fix instead of creating my own solution. You will have to test it, only real change is that at location you used S3GetObjectRequest you will use LargeFileS3GetObjectRequest. For me it worked while downloading some 4gb of data in total, files from 1 mb to 700mb (Tested on iPod touch 4g).

Comment: Thanks, Ill give it a shot when I get back to that point in my project. Should be in a day or so. Ill be sure to msg you if I run into problems. Thanks again.

Comment: Hey, its that time. I've got a couple of questions about you're implementation. In LargeFileS3GetObjectRequest do you implement anything? and LargeFileS3GetObjectResponse do you implement the rest of the delegate methods?

Comment: There is no need to implement anything else, you just use the Amazon's S3GetObjectResponse/Request functionality as usual, and override single method this way to get rid of it keeping all the data it downloaded in RAM. Strategy is to open a stream and whenever you receive data as you normally would, you just write it to stream. That means also that you will get NULL as data upon successfully completing download, so you could track it's size when ever you receive data in delegate. You can also get upfront the size of the file and last modified using normal AWS S3 calls like S3GetObjectMetadata.

Comment: I ended up implemented it with using stream when I tried using the modified methods it wouldn't work. As in my file would always stay 0 bytes.  So I went back and now it works.  No idea why.  I have a lot more testing to do though. You help is appreciated.

Comment: If this turns to be a correct answer could you please mark it as such?

Answer (score 3):

I am a maintainer of the AWS SDK for iOS.  We recently patched the S3GetObjectResponse to allow the streaming of the data directly to disk without keeping the response data in memory.

[S3GetObjectResponse.m](https://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-ios/blob/4bdf4a9dc838d2ed63cc4732865894af3a39e9ed/src/Amazon.S3/Model/S3GetObjectResponse.m)

To enable this, you simply need to set the stream when creating your request:

```
NSOutputStream *outputStream = [[[NSOutputStream alloc] initToFileAtPath:FILE_NAME append:NO] autorelease];
[outputStream open];
S3GetObjectRequest *getObjectRequest = [[[S3GetObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:FILE_NAME withBucket:BUCKET_NAME] autorelease];
getObjectRequest.outputStream = outputStream;
[s3 getObject:getObjectRequest];
```

**Update**: We added a post to our AWS Mobile Developer Blog on [downloading large files with the AWS SDK for iOS](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/TxJFT163EJ18CA/Downloading-Large-Files-from-Amazon-S3-with-the-AWS-SDK-for-iOS&ei=SL7uUfjLIcviyAG534CYCw&usg=AFQjCNGOkAikgJOqYWIThr6tMg4x6slWKg&sig2=criniYUdT9WINhz9YTVyNw&bvm=bv.49641647,d.aWc) that includes this info as well as other tips.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to stream the data to your application via ASIHTTPRequest

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/S3

```
NSString *secretAccessKey = @"my-secret-access-key";
NSString *accessKey = @"my-access-key";
NSString *bucket = @"my-bucket";
NSString *path = @"path/to/the/object";

ASIS3ObjectRequest *request = [ASIS3ObjectRequest requestWithBucket:bucket key:path];
[request setSecretAccessKey:secretAccessKey];
[request setAccessKey:accessKey];
[request startSynchronous];
if (![request error]) {
    NSData *data = [request responseData];
} else {
    NSLog(@"%@",[[request error] localizedDescription]);
}
```

Comment: I prefer not to use something that not being maintained.

Comment: Well it was the best for a long time.  Let me know if you find something with all of it's features (stream from disk, S3, etc).

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Set up the Amazon client */
_s3 = [[AmazonS3Client alloc] initWithAccessKey:k_Amazon_ACCESS_KEY_ID withSecretKey:k_Amazon_SECRET_KEY];
_s3.endpoint = [AmazonEndpoints s3Endpoint:SA_EAST_1];

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{

    /* Open a file stream for the download */
    NSOutputStream *outputStream = [[NSOutputStream alloc] initToFileAtPath:[DOCUMENTS_DIRECTORY stringByAppendingPathComponent:k_Amazon_Video_Local_File_Name] append:NO];
    [outputStream open];

    /* Set up the s3 get object */

    S3GetObjectRequest *getVideoRequest = [[S3GetObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:k_Amazon_Video_Path withBucket:@""];

    /* Set the stream */

    getVideoRequest.outputStream = outputStream;

    /* Get the response from Amazon */

    S3GetObjectResponse *getObjectResponse = [_s3 getObject:getVideoRequest];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        if(getObjectResponse.error != nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"S3 Error: %@", getObjectResponse.error);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"S3 - Video download complete and successful");
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:k_Amazon_Video_Downloaded];
        }

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];

    });
});
```